# CSS Central Column for Content

Tags: html, css

I am almost certain that this question has been asked and answered before, however I have failed to find it, maybe because I just cannot explain myself properly in words. What I currently have is a design for my new website, but what I cannot seem to figure out is how to make a central column for content. Let me illustrate for you.

This is what it currently looks like:

http://pbrd.co/1yPNMtT

And this is what I would like it to look like:

http://pbrd.co/1yPO6ZD

Apologies if I am not making myself clear enough. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show your code what you have tried

Comment: keep one container div and apply it `width:1000px; margin:0px auto;`

Comment: The next time try to upload the images here instead of use another site: it is faster look the images here than follow a link

Comment: @Narkha I was unable to upload images here due to my reputation being too low, so I uploaded them to an external site.

Comment: @GaganGami I haven't tried any code yet simply because I am a complete idiot when it comes to front end stuff (CSS & HTML), I haven't even tried anything yet since I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/VzGAy/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.centerDiv {
  
  text-align: center;
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:cyan;

}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
  <div class="centerDiv">center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.. ( ಠ_ಠ)

Comment: In regards to your edit, it's worked well. However the navigation bar is a fixed style, therefore the first part of the body falls behinds it. How can I overcome this?

Comment: You can add, for example, 'position:relative' and 'margin: 5% 0 0 0 (remember top, right, bottom, left) to the centerDiv class.

Comment: Works well, and better than other methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest could be to set the container margin to `auto` and give a value to the width of your content

assuming

```
<main class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</main>
```

your css could be

```
.container{
  margin:'auto';
}

.content{
  width:80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the white div you should set width and then margin:0 auto; for it to align to center.
For the H1 you can use width:100%; text-align:center;

```
<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <h1>Content Here</h1>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    body {
        width:100%;
    }

    #main-content {
        float:none;
        width:1200px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #main-content h1 {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This method seemed to work best. Thank you very much. Also I would give you reputation but I don't have enough myself to do so. So apologies for that.